# Can I use 'I' in an essay?

Tags: writing, writing-advice

Can I use 'I' in an essay, can I address myself and explain things from my perspective ? (without twisting or bending facts of course)

Comment: What kind of "essay"?  Poetry?  Family history?  Economics?  Medicine?

Comment: generally academic, raising an issue, proving a point type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern essay style accepts the use of "I", especially in preference to older uses of passive voice that now tend to look stilted, e.g. "one would opine" or "it was thought" rather than "I think".

Comment: "one would opine" isn't a "passive" construction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It was opined by me that your comment is accurate.